# How do set network profile priorities?

Tags: networking

I have two wired connection settings, one is a direct connect with a static ip and gateway and the other is all set by dhcp.

I sporadically use the first to connect directly to a certain device, but I'm mostly using the second on normal days.

The thing is that ubuntu connects by default to the first, which obviously doesn't work. I have then to select the second profile manually.

How can I tell the network manager to use the second profile by default?

Answer (score 0):

I am on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 and had similar issues, this worked for me:

The connection I wanted prioritized was my DHCP network. On that network profile I went into the Identity tab and made sure "Connect automatically" was checked.

On the profile with static IP, I made sure the same option was unchecked.
[image: Network profile settings picture on imgur]